# Windows Desktop Search 4 or Windows 7 Search add in for Lotus Notes

Tags: windows-7, lotus-notes, desktop-search

Does anyone know if a [Windows Desktop Search](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/default.mspx) Add-in (also called IFilter) exists for Lotus Notes that will work with Windows Desktop Search 4.0 (installs on older OS's and is included in Windows 7)? Microsoft had one for older versions of Desktop Search:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ac768e36-be57-4306-966c-5089b0c4d50e&DisplayLang=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a new Lotus Notes Add-in for WDS on XP and Windows Search for Windows 7.  It is available at www.notesconnectors.com.  Enables users to search their email, archives, attachments and files at the same time.  Works with any version of Notes over 6.5.